# How to restrict to add data against same user id - using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have some post data and storing it against user id and I want if data is already saved against same user id and if I hit request again against same user id it should not add this data.

My code is below:

```
     $this->medicalIdentifiers->user_id = $doctorProfile['user_id'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->medical_credentials = $doctorProfile['medical_credentials'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->registration_number = $doctorProfile['registration_number'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->registration_expiration_date = $doctorProfile['registration_expiration_date'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->dea_number = $doctorProfile['dea_number'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->dea_expiration_date = $doctorProfile['dea_expiration_date'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->dea_issue_date = $doctorProfile['dea_issue_date'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->npi_number = $doctorProfile['npi_number'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->billing_title = $doctorProfile['billing_title'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->billing_employment_type = $doctorProfile['billing_employment_type'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->other_employment_type = $doctorProfile['other_employment_type'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->nadean_number = $doctorProfile['nadean_number'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->upin = $doctorProfile['upin'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->wcb_authorization = $doctorProfile['wcb_authorization'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->wcb_rating_code = $doctorProfile['wcb_rating_code'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->wcb_date_of_issue = $doctorProfile['wcb_date_of_issue'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->hospital_privileges = $doctorProfile['hospital_privileges'];
            $this->medicalIdentifiers->save();
```

I am passing user_id in request and I am using Postman to hit request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique index in the database in non-repeating fields or before you save the model, you need to check the query to the database or there is such data for your user

```
$medicalIdentifiers = DB::table('youre_table')->where([['user_id', '=', $doctorProfile['user_id']], ['medical_credentials', '=', $doctorProfile['medical_credentials']/*..another field..*/]])->get();

if (!$medicalIdentifiers) {
    //...save
}
```